# Mercurial What is Wrong with this command?

Tags: mercurial

```
Y:\>hg -R Y:/mercFlow.cache/vm-linux rename Migration-2010/create_directory_stru
cture.pl Migration-2010/create_directory_structure.pl2
abort: Migration-2010/create_directory_structure.pl not under root
```

I am in windows using Mercurial. I am trying to rename\move a file as a simple test. Y:/mercFlow.cache/vm-linx/Migration-2010/create_directory_structure.pl exists and is brow-sable in the file browser. Migration-2010/create_directory_Structure.pl most definitely does seem to exist under the vm-linux local repository.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use paths relative to your current working directory when you use `hg -R` -- that is, the `-R` option does not change the working directory of the `hg` proceess. The `--cwd` option *does* change the working directory.

This illustrates the difference:

```
$ hg init test
$ echo hello > test/hello.txt
$ hg -R test add test/hello.txt
$ hg -R test status test/hello.txt
A test/hello.txt
$ hg --cwd test status hello.txt
A hello.txt
```

and this does not work:

```
$ hg -R test status hello.txt
abort: hello.txt not under root
$ hg --cwd test status test/hello.txt
test/hello.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Pitty there's no mention of this at http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#options

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: It's a little implicit now, yes. Maybe you could submit a patch with better help strings for the options? Please see http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ContributingChanges.

Comment: Newer versions of Mercurial apparently show a hint *(consider using '--cwd <path-to-repo-root>')* when using `-R, --repository` option together with any option taking file name pattern when the file name pattern is not rooted in the specified repository root directory.

Answer (score 0):

is `Migration-2010/create_directory_structure.pl` under version control?  It has to be in your Mercurial repository before you can manipulate it with Mercurial.

Comment: Yes it is under Version Control.